# Qt 5.0.2 + Mingw-builds (4.8.1) webkit linkage error

Tags: c++, qt, mingw, qt5, mingw-w64

I am trying to build Qt 5.0.2 with Mingw-builds (4.8.1), but during webkit building i have linking error:

```
C:/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.0.2/qtwebkit/Source/WebKit/release/libWebKit1.a(FullScreenVideoQt.o):FullScreenVideoQt.cpp:(.text+0x143): undefined reference to `WebCore::HTMLMediaElement::platformMedia() const'
C:/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.0.2/qtwebkit/Source/WebKit/release/libWebKit1.a(FullScreenVideoQt.o):FullScreenVideoQt.cpp:(.text+0x19e): undefined reference to `WebCore::HTMLMediaElement::platformMedia() const'
C:/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.0.2/qtwebkit/Source/WebKit/release/libWebKit1.a(FullScreenVideoQt.o):FullScreenVideoQt.cpp:(.text+0xe5): undefined reference to `WebCore::HTMLMediaElement::exitFullscreen()'
c:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.0.2/qtwebkit/Source/WebKit/release/libWebKit1.a(FullScreenVideoQt.o): bad reloc address 0x0 in section `.pdata'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile.api.Release:81: recipe for target '..\lib\Qt5WebKit.dll' failed
mingw32-make[4]: *** [..\lib\Qt5WebKit.dll] Error 1
mingw32-make[4]: Leaving directory 'c:/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.0.2/qtwebkit/Source'
Makefile.api:52: recipe for target 'release-all' failed
mingw32-make[3]: *** [release-all] Error 2
mingw32-make[3]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
C:/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.0.2/qtwebkit/Source/WebKit/debug/libWebKit1d.a(FullScreenVideoQt.o):FullScreenVideoQt.cpp:(.text+0x94): undefined reference to `WebCore::ChromeClientQt::createFullScreenVideoHandler()'
C:/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.0.2/qtwebkit/Source/WebKit/debug/libWebKit1d.a(FullScreenVideoQt.o):FullScreenVideoQt.cpp:(.text+0x163): undefined reference to `WebCore::HTMLMediaElement::platformMedia() const'
C:/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.0.2/qtwebkit/Source/WebKit/debug/libWebKit1d.a(FullScreenVideoQt.o):FullScreenVideoQt.cpp:(.text+0x1c7): undefined reference to `WebCore::HTMLMediaElement::platformMedia() const'
C:/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.0.2/qtwebkit/Source/WebKit/debug/libWebKit1d.a(FullScreenVideoQt.o):FullScreenVideoQt.cpp:(.text+0x293): undefined reference to `WebCore::HTMLMediaElement::platformMedia() const'
C:/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.0.2/qtwebkit/Source/WebKit/debug/libWebKit1d.a(FullScreenVideoQt.o):FullScreenVideoQt.cpp:(.text+0x122): undefined reference to `WebCore::HTMLMediaElement::exitFullscreen()'
c:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.0.2/qtwebkit/Source/WebKit/debug/libWebKit1d.a(FullScreenVideoQt.o): bad reloc address 0x0 in section `.pdata'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile.api.Debug:81: recipe for target '..\lib\Qt5WebKitd.dll' failed
mingw32-make[4]: *** [..\lib\Qt5WebKitd.dll] Error 1
mingw32-make[4]: Leaving directory 'c:/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.0.2/qtwebkit/Source'
Makefile.api:38: recipe for target 'debug-all' failed
mingw32-make[3]: *** [debug-all] Error 2
mingw32-make[3]: Leaving directory 'c:/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.0.2/qtwebkit/Source'
Makefile.QtWebKit:43: recipe for target 'sub-api-pri-all-ordered' failed
mingw32-make[2]: *** [sub-api-pri-all-ordered] Error 2
mingw32-make[2]: Leaving directory 'c:/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.0.2/qtwebkit/Source'
Makefile:221: recipe for target 'sub-Source-QtWebKit-pro-all-ordered' failed
mingw32-make[1]: *** [sub-Source-QtWebKit-pro-all-ordered] Error 2
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory 'c:/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.0.2/qtwebkit'
Makefile:233: recipe for target 'module-qtwebkit-all' failed
mingw32-make: *** [module-qtwebkit-all] Error 2
```

So, does anybody know how i can fix this error, and is it possible to build Qt 5.0.2 with MinGW on windows?

P.S. My configure command:

```
>configure.bat -debug-and-release -developer-build -opensource -icu -opengl desktop -platform win32-g++ -c++11 -shared -nomake examples -nomake demos -nomake tests -prefix C:\Libs\Qt
```

Comment: maybe I'm wrong, but: "-platform win32-g++" seems strange with a 64 bit mingw ... Are there no other platforms, more appropriate for 64 bit? (I don't have a QT right now, I can check later)

Comment: There are no any win64* mkspecs, only win32* (win32-msvc2012, win32-g++, win32-icc, etc...).

Comment: hm, ok ... according to the error, "WebCore::HTMLMediaElement::platformMedia() const" is not found ... Can you please do a quick grep for the definition of the method to see that it is there, just to exclude this possibility? Meanwhile: http://qt-project.org/wiki/MinGW-64-bit

Answer (score 1):

It sounds strange, but when i done build in another directory with another -prefix option for 'configure' script build have finished successfully... So, question is closed? thanks all for responses...